# Rails gives 404 instead of 405 on wrong method used in HTTP call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller action mentioned in routes as -

```
get '/landing' => 'main#landing_page', as: :my_landing_page
```

since it is a get method, I want to take care of cases where some user hits a POSt request on this one (Right now a POST request on `/landing` gives me 404 instead of a `405`.

Please help me how to fix it. I found [this being filed as a bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28228#), where they said I need to fix it in `resources`, but I couldn't make out where to fix that. I am new to it.

Answer (score 2):

In your `config/routes.rb`

`post "/landing", to: "errors#method_not_allowed"`

and `app/controllers/errors_controller.rb`

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def method_not_allowed
    head :not_found
  end

end
```